# Problema de actualizar al cambiar de páginas

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap

Dentro de la página web que estoy creando al cambiar de páginas tengo que volver a cargar la página en la que me encuentre para que así cargue todo de manera correcta.

He estado mirando mucho y no he encontrado una solución espero que podáis ayudarme, probé metiendo un **setInterval** cada vez que se abría una nueva página para que se actualizara, pero aún así había que actualizarla manualmente y luego ya cogía la función de actualizar.

Un ejemplo sería este:

```
function JSONRequest() {

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=.&number=5');
request.onload = function () {
    let todo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    let contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor')
    console.log(todo)
    for (let i = 0; i < todo.results.length; i++) {

        let card = document.createElement('div')
        card.setAttribute('class', 'list-group list-boxes carta-rece')
        card.setAttribute('name', 'links')
        let enlace = document.createElement('a');
        enlace.setAttribute('href', 'prueba.html');
        // enlace.className="border border-mandarina rounded-s shadow-xxs"
        enlace.innerHTML = todo.results[i].title
        card.appendChild(enlace)
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = "img-api";
        img.setAttribute('name', 'links')
        img.src = todo.results[i].image;
        card.appendChild(img)
        contenedor.appendChild(card)

    }
    let links = document.getElementsByName('links');
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            let = local = localStorage.setItem("recetaid", JSON.stringify(todo.results[i]));

        }, false)

    }
}
request.send();
```

}

Al entrar en el enlace que crea a la siguiente (prueba.html) página no carga sola. En este ejemplo que muestro utilizo JavaScript, pero tampoco funciona con las páginas de PHP. Para el resto de páginas y en general la página web estoy utilizando una plantilla que se llama StickyMobile.

Gracias.

Comment: Duplicada de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536666/problema-al-cambiar-de-p%c3%a1ginas, por favor no uséis diferentes usuarios para postear preguntas idénticas...

Comment: @Benito-B Perdón, me cree una cuenta no podía ya borrar ni acceder a la pregunta, entonces la volví a realizar, si sabes como borrarla te lo agradecería...

Comment: He pedido la intervención de un moderador para que te ayude a unificar tus cuentas y tus preguntas. Por otra parte, no queda muy claro cuál es el problema, ni el contexto en que éste ocurre. También, evita publicar tus API Keys en preguntas...

Comment: Gracias por lo de las cuentas y preguntas @A.Cedano, es que es un problema raro y no se explicarlo muy bien, te pongo en situación..., estamos en el "index.html" y queremos ir a "ejemplo.html"(en este archivo aparte del html y css hace una llamada para mostrar los datos de una API), pues al entrar desde "index.html" a "ejemplo.html" no carga nada automaticamente, asi que si quieres que la pagina cargue todo del todo hay que recargarla manualmente (con F5, por ejemplo).

Comment: Parece que no hacen falta dos páginas para esto. Al entrar a `index.html` puedes mandar a pedir los datos a la API lanzando una petición `fetch` o Ajax desde el DOMContentLoaded, y, si quieres seguir trayendo datos, puedes lanzar la petición cada X tiempo desde el mismo sitio. ¿Por qué te lías con dos páginas? Aparte de eso, el problema en sí mismo puede ser que la petición Ajax no esté funcionando, o que esté escrita de forma errónea. Todo eso será simple de depurar, cuando tengas claro el contexto, que es, a mi juicio, el principal problema aquí.

Comment: No es necesaria la fusion ya que tu otra cuenta no esta registrada y no tiene absolutamente nada.. directamente si me das tu permiso, borro la cuenta y la publicacion....

Comment: @gbianchi Si, borra todo eso sin problemas, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque debes navegar por tus directorios al usar un enlace, si este fuese a un link externo deberias usar https://pagina.com pero como debes ir a un archivo html dentro de tu proyecto debes escribir la ruta, ejemplo:

```
carpetaRaiz
    carpeta
        prueba.html
    index.html
```

entonces tu enlace deberia ser en este caso:

```
<a href="/carpetaRaiz/carpeta/prueba.html">Ir al enlace</a>
```

Puedes hacerlo de una manera mas resumida de esta forma

```
<a href="./carpeta/prueba.html">Ir al enlace</a>
```

o

```
<a href="../carpeta/prueba.html">Ir al enlace</a>
```

si el index.html esta dentro de una carpeta en la carpeta raiz
ejemplo:

```
carpetaRaiz
    carpeta
       prueba.html
    carpeta2
       index.html
```

el primer punto antes del './' significa salir del archivo en este caso index.html, el segundo punto '..' es para salir del archivo y de la carpeta donde esta ese archivo y ya luego solo accedes a la carpeta y archivo html

```
/carpeta/prueba.html
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y lo bien que lo has explicado.

Comment: no es nada, usualmente no se habla mucho de estas cosas por lo cual es difícil encontrar respuestas.